# $4(x^4_1+x^4_2+\cdots + x^4_{14})=7(x^3_1+x^3_2+\cdots + x^3_{14})$ has no solution in positive integers.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $$4(x^4_1+x^4_2+\cdots + x^4_{14})=7(x^3_1+x^3_2+\cdots + x^3_{14})$$ has no solution in positive integers.

I do not know where to begin. I tried to expand $\sum_{k=1}^{14} (x_k -1)^4$ but couldn't deduce anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rearrange the equation to

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{14} (4x_i^4 - 7x_i^3) = 0 $$

If $x_i \geq 2$, then
$$4x_i^4 - 7x_i^3 = (4 x_i - 7) x_i^3 \geq 8$$

so the terms in the sum are only negative if $x_i=1$, giving $4x_i^4 - 7x_i^3 = -3$.

If $x_i \geq 3$, then $4x_i^4 - 7x_i^3 \geq 135$, so there must be at least $135/3 = 45$ other terms of $-3$ to total zero. There aren't that many elements in the sum, so this is impossible. Every $x_i$ must be either $1$ or $2$.

If $m$ is the number of $x_i$ equal to $2$, then $14-m$ is the number of $x_i$ equal to $1$, and the sum is

$$8m + (-3)(14-m) = 0$$

Which would imply $m = \frac{42}{11}$, but that's not a natural number, so can't be a count of summands.

So there is no solution in positive integers.